# Me borra el primer elemento de la lista

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json, mongodb

Tengo un programa desarrollado en js, donde uso node y mongoDB, tengo todo el programa construido y funcional, sin embargo, tengo un error en la funcionalidad del botón borrar, este, efectivamente me borra los datos, sin embargo, me borra únicamente el primer elemento del json, cuando lo que quiero realmente es que dependiendo del botón que pulse, pues me borre en concreto el que quiero, no obstante independientemente al botón que le de, me borra siempre de uno en uno siguiendo un orden, adjunto el fragmento de mi script donde hago la función de la base de datos, para borrar, y el site.js donde ejecuto la función del botón borrar. En conclusión, lo que quiero conseguir es que si pulso el boton borrar de la fila de un personaje en concreto, me borre ese que he seleccionado y no el primero que este en la lista, habia pensado en realizado un switch, pero un switch con 24 personajes indicando el nombre concreto de cada uno, me parece que no es la forma mas funcional precisamente.

```js
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    //IMPORTAR JSON
    $("#boton-Importar-json").on('click', function (event) {
        console.log("has pulsado el botón importar json");
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/importar-json", function (datos) {
            $("#contenedor").html(datos);
        });
    });

    //LLAMADA A MOSTRAR TODOS LOS PERSONAJES
    $("#boton-MostrarTodos").on('click', function (event) {
        console.log("has pulsado el botón bd");
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/consultas", function (datos) {
            $("#contenedor").html(datos);
             //FUNCIONALIDAD BOTON BORAR
             $(".boton-borrar").on("click", function () {
                console.log("Has pulsado el boton borrar")
                let nombre = $(this).data('name');
                console.log(nombre);
                $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/borrar",{borrar:nombre}, function (datos) {
                    $("#contenedor").html(datos);
                });
            });
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
    });

    //LLAMADA A MOSTRAR HUMANOS
    $("#boton-humanos").on('click', function (event) {
        console.log("has pulsado el botón humanos");
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/especies", function (datos) {
            $("#contenedor").html(datos);
            //FUNCIONALIDAD BOTON BORAR
            $(".boton-borrar").on("click", function () {
                console.log("Has pulsado el boton borrar")
                let nombre = $(this).data('name');
                console.log(nombre);
                $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/borrar",{borrar:nombre}, function (datos) {
                    $("#contenedor").html(datos);
                });
            });
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
    });

    //LLAMADA BOTON AÑO DE NACIMIENTO
    $("#boton-anio").on('click', function (event) {
        console.log("has pulsado el botón anio nacimiento");
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/nacimientos", function (datos) {
            $("#contenedor").html(datos);
             //FUNCIONALIDAD BOTON BORAR
             $(".boton-borrar").on("click", function () {
                console.log("Has pulsado el boton borrar")
                let nombre = $(this).data('name');
                console.log(nombre);
                $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/borrar",{borrar:nombre}, function (datos) {
                    $("#contenedor").html(datos);
                });
            });
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });

    });

    //LLAMADA BOTÓN VARITAS
    $("#boton-holly").on('click', function (event) {
        console.log("has pulsado el botón holly");
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/varitas", function (datos) {
            $("#contenedor").html(datos);
             //FUNCIONALIDAD BOTON BORAR
             $(".boton-borrar").on("click", function () {
                console.log("Has pulsado el boton borrar")
                let nombre = $(this).data('name');
                console.log(nombre);
                $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/borrar",{borrar:nombre}, function (datos) {
                    $("#contenedor").html(datos);
                });
            });
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });

    });

    //LLAMADA BOTÓN ESTUDIANTES
    $("#boton-estudiantes").on('click', function (event) {
        console.log("has pulsado el botón estudiantes");
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/estudiantes", function (datos) {
            $("#contenedor").html(datos);
             //FUNCIONALIDAD BOTON BORAR
             $(".boton-borrar").on("click", function () {
                console.log("Has pulsado el boton borrar")
                let nombre = $(this).data('name');
                console.log(nombre);
                $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/borrar",{borrar:nombre}, function (datos) {
                    $("#contenedor").html(datos);
                });
            });
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });

    });
})
```

```css
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var moduloBd = require('./bd');

http.createServer(function (peticion, respuesta) {
    respuesta.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    respuesta.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST,OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    var url_peticion = url.parse(peticion.url, true);
    var pathname = url_peticion.pathname;
    console.log(pathname);

    //RUTA INICIAL
    if (pathname == '/') {
        respuesta.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8'
        });
        respuesta.write('<p><b>Dumbeldore:</b> ¡Bienvenido a Howarts estudiante.!</p>');
        respuesta.end();
    }
    else if (pathname == '/borrar') {
        console.log("Estoy en index.js");
        let parametros = url_peticion.query;
        console.log("El personaje a borrar es:")
        console.log(parametros.borrar)
        moduloBd.borrar(parametros.borrar, function (salida) {
            respuesta.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8'
            });
            respuesta.write(salida);
            respuesta.end();
        }, parametros.name);
    }
    //ERROR DE RUTA
    else {
        respuesta.writeHead(404, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8'
        });
        respuesta.write('<p>Lo sentimos, la ruta indicada no existe.</p>');
        respuesta.end();
    }

}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1'), (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    }
    console.log('Servidor ejecutándose en 127.0.0.1:8080/');
}
```

```html
/*con (respuesta,data) si borra, pero solo va  borrando el primer elemento cada vez que se le da al
boton borrar.
*/
exports.borrar = function (data,respuesta) {
    console.log("Estamos dentro de la función borrar");
    console.log(data);
    MongoCli.connect(mongoUrl, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        var dbo = db.db("harry");
        console.log("Hasta aqui llega");
        var query = {"name":data};
        //var query = {"name":data.borrar}; <---- No funciona
        dbo.collection("personajes").deleteOne(
            query,
            function (err, result) {
                console.log("El error es = " + err)
                if (err) throw err;
                db.close();
            }
        );
        console.log(respuesta);
    })
}
```

Comment: ¿Esta es la forma correcta de especificar lo que se quiere borrar `var query = {"name":data};`? En la petición estás enviando un objeto `{borrar:nombre}`, lo que me hace pensar que debería ser algo como `var query = {"name":data.borrar};`

Comment: Buenas, si lo cambio la sentencia a como dices, var query = {"name":data.borrar};, el programa no logra borrar nada, detecta el boton y su funcion, pero no lo borra.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para poner el código actualizado y el que usas para ejecutar `exports.borrar()`

Comment: Código export actualizado

Comment: Te faltó incluir el código con el que lo ejecutas y la salida en consola, lo que tienes en la imagen, pero actualizado y como texto.

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza, ya esta actualizado